# ASP.NET application is not able to find or connect to DSN of 64 bit Oracle Driver with error Data source name not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, odbc, iis-7.5

I have developed ASP.Net application which is connecting to Oracle Database using ODBC via DSN connection.
Everything works on my local development environment but after I deployed in IIS, it is unable to connect to database & logs below error.

> ```
> ***[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified***
> ```

Then I started looking for solution & tried below things but nothing worked.

1. Checked the application is developed using Platform Any CPU.
2. DSN is configured & Tested Connection using Oracle client 64 bit ODBC Data Source. On 64 bit server DSN can be configured for 64 bit & 32 bit also.
3. Tried with setting permissions to DSN in registry for the apppool identity user.
4. Tried AppPool Setting for Enable 32Bit Application to True, in this case it give another error that ODBC & application architecture mismatch.

Please let me know if any more alternative is there, otherwise I am thinking of installing 32bit oracle client & try to connect using 32bit ODBC DSN.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built the code using X64 platform & then deployed it in IIS.
I was using 11.2.0 client so it started reading the DSN but ***Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow*** exception. This is issue in the driver need to install the patch.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariae/2012/07/05/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-error-running-a-report-that-uses-a-connection-data-source-to-oracle-10/

Answer (score 0):

Found this link very helpful.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/942976
It says about the visibility of DSN connections for 32bit & 64bit applications.
Tried with small test utility (winform) & the behaviour for 32bit & 64 bit application can be distinquished.
But unable to find the solution for ASP.Net application.